# Visual Studio build question

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build, gac

In my project I am referencing an assembly produced by another team in my company. That assembly itself references three third-part assemblies one of which is Oracle.DataAccess. Whenever I build my project the assembly I directly reference and two of the three assemblies it references are copied to my output bin directory. Only Oracle.DataAccess is not copied. I have CopyLocal set to true for the referenced assembly. I also uninstalled Oracle.DataAccess from the GAC at the suggestion of a stackoverflow thread. Any ideas how I can get Oracle.DataAccess copied to the bin folder when I build my project?

Thanks a lot in advance.